# PHP StdErr after Exec()

Tags: php, exec, stderr

In PHP I am executing a command with exec(), and it returns if successful an URL;

```
$url = exec('report');
```

However, I want to check stderr, if something went wrong. How would I read the stream?
I want to use php://stderr, but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: I will recommend you to use Symfony/Process component.

Comment: @martin Is there an answer which helped you? Please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 86):

If you want to execute a command, and get both `stderr` and `stdout`, not "merged", a solution would probably to use [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), which provides a great level of control over the command that's being executed -- including a way to pipe `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr`.

And here is an example : let's consider we have this shell-script, in `test.sh`, which writes to both `stderr` and `stdout` :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'this is on stdout';
echo 'this is on stdout too';

echo 'this is on stderr' >&2;
echo 'this is on stderr too' >&2;
```

Now, let's code some PHP, in `temp.php` -- first, we initialize the i/o descriptors :

```
$descriptorspec = [
   0 => ["pipe", "r"],  // stdin
   1 => ["pipe", "w"],  // stdout
   2 => ["pipe", "w"],  // stderr
];
```

And, then, execute the `test.sh` command, using those descriptors, in the current directory, and saying the i/o should be from/to `$pipes` :

```
$process = proc_open('./test.sh', $descriptorspec, $pipes, dirname(__FILE__), null);
```

We can now read from the two output pipes :

```
$stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);

$stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
```

And, if we output the content of those two variables :

```
echo "stdout : \n";
var_dump($stdout);

echo "stderr :\n";
var_dump($stderr);
```

We get the following output when executing the `temp.php` script :

```
$ php ./temp.php
stdout :
string(40) "this is on stdout
this is on stdout too
"
stderr :
string(40) "this is on stderr
this is on stderr too
"
```

Comment: When using this, make sure you all use proc_close when you're all done for cleanliness' sake.

Comment: Why you redirect result in a process var?

Comment: @BriceFavre He puts it in a process var so that he can close it later with proc_close, which will also return the return code the process exited with.

`$returnCode = proc_close( $process );`

Comment: in Windows evironments, `proc_open` seems to be unreliable.

Comment: How to merge both pipes together, in the order the data comes in?

Answer (score 59):

A little function that might be helpful:

```
function my_shell_exec($cmd, &$stdout=null, &$stderr=null) {
    $proc = proc_open($cmd,[
        1 => ['pipe','w'],
        2 => ['pipe','w'],
    ],$pipes);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    return proc_close($proc);
}
```

The exit code is returned and STDOUT and STDERR are reference params if you need them.

Comment: Kind of surprising they haven't implemented something like this into stock PHP yet.

Answer (score 11):

The short way to do such a things with `exec` is to return the exit code ( status of the command )

Note that I am trying to list a non-exists directory `/non-dir/`

```
exec('ls /non-dir/', $out, $retval);
var_dump($retval);
```

Output

> ls: cannot access '/non-dir/': No such file or directory
>   int(2)

Normally in unix-based system most of successful statuses codes is ( **0** ) so you can check your `$retval` to know the status of the command.

to dismiss the error from listing an invalid path `ls: cannot access '/non-dir/': No such file or directory` you can redirect your **stderr** to null

```
exec('ls /non-dir/ 2>/dev/null', $out, $retval);
var_dump($retval);
```

this will output :

> int(2)

also if you need the error string to use it in any scenario you may redirect your **stderr** to the **stdout**.

```
exec('ls /non-dir/ 2>&1', $out, $retval);
print_r($out);
var_dump($retval);
```

this will output the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ls: cannot access '/non-dir/': No such file or directory
)
int(2)
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way to get unmerged stdout/stderr.

```
$pp_name = "/tmp/pp_test";
@unlink($pp_name);
posix_mkfifo($pp_name, 0777);
$pp = fopen($pp_name, "r+");
stream_set_blocking($pp, FALSE);
exec("wget -O - http://www.youtube.com 2>$pp_name", $r_stdout);
$r_stderr = stream_get_contents($pp);
var_dump($r_stderr);
fclose($pp);
unlink($pp_name);
```

If you want to ignore stdout and get only stderr, you can try this:

```
exec("wget -O - http://www.youtube.com 2>&1 >/dev/null", $r_stderr);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
exec("{$command} 2>&1"
    ,$output
    ,$exitCode
    );
```

- *2>&1* redirects stderr to stdout for consistent success / fail behaviour.
- *$exitCode* determines *$command* completion status.
- *$output* contains all output associated with *$exitCode*.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly ugly but good enough. Put the stderr into a temp file and read it back.

```
$tmp = tempnam("/tmp", "ERR_");
exec('report 2> ' . escapeshellarg($tmp), $stdout, $retcode);
$stderr = file_get_contents($tmp);
unlink($tmp);
if ($retcode == 0)
{
    // good
    $url = $stdout[0];
} else {
    // bad
    error_log("FAIL: $stderr");
}
```