# How to capture stderr from command line in PHP

Tags: php, c, compiler-construction

I want to create an online compiler of C/C++.

Till now I have developed the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{


    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    compile();
}
function compile()
{
$a=shell_exec('gcc -o Compile Compile.c');
echo $a;
$b=shell_exec('./Compile');
echo $b;
}
?>
```

The file Compile.c is getting uploaded and after that compiled by gcc.
What I want to do is:

- Read error from stderr when compilation results in error and display on webpage.
- If no error then execute the code on an input file and display time of execution, if time  exceeds a particular value, then show time limit exceeded error.

I searched internet and found that if compilation statement is appended by "2>&1" as

```
$a=shell_exec('gcc -o Compile Compile.c 2>&1');
```

Then the output of compilation error is returned to assigned variable($a in above case), but not without it. So my problem is how to check for error and then display it on webpage without appending "2>&1" and if no error, then carry out second step given above .

Comment: If it works with `2>&1`, why don't you just use that?

Comment: If I use 2>&1, I wont be able to know that whether it is error or not.

Comment: Use proc_open when you need greater control of the process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320608/php-stderr-after-exec.

Comment: Does proc_open() execute shell command? I tried to compile c using proc_open(), but it was not responding correctly. Maybe I used some wrong arguments.

Answer (score 6):

The correct use of proc_open() would look like this:

```
$process = proc_open('gcc -o Compile Compile.c', array(
    0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // STDIN
    1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // STDOUT
    2 => array('pipe', 'w')  // STDERR
), $pipes);

if(is_resource($process)) {
    // If you want to write to STDIN
    fwrite($pipes[0], '...');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    $stdOut = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    $stdErr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    $returnCode = proc_close($process);
}
```

This would execute the shell command and give you detailed control of STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR.

Answer (score 0):

PHP contains a plethora of functions for executing external processes, each with it's own set of defiencies.

In this particular case, you might be able to hold on to some simplicity by using `exec` (and redirecting stderr to stdout with `2>&1`). The return value, although a string, is useless; it's only the last line of the output; however, the second argument ought to be an array that is filled with the output (an entry per line), and the third argument, `return_var` will tell you whether the compilation succeeded or not: `0` means success, anything else a failure.