# exec command is not working on Linux server

Tags: java, php, linux

I call a Java function using PHP. The code is:

```
exec('pushd d:\xampp\htdocs\file_excecute\class & java Autoingestion username password id   Sales Daily Summary 20120902',$output,$return);
```

This code worked on a Windows machine but it is not working on a Linux server. The code is:

```
exec('pushd \var\www\domainname.com\itune_report\class & java Autoingestion username password id Sales Weekly Summary 20120901',$output,$return);
```

Comment: Linux uses forward slashes to specify path components. Did you try replacing your back slashes with forward slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of slash as a field separator, but that may not be your only problem.

The output of the command appears in $output, since you use the `exec(command, output, return)` form.

However, this only gives you stdout. The shell will send error messages to stderr.

Unfortunately there isn't a version of `exec()` that reads stderr.

You can merge both outputs to `$output` by adding `2>&1` at the end of your shell command:

```
exec("mycommand 2>&1", $output, $return);
```

Look at $output, and you will *either* find the output of your successful command *or* error messages which you can use to work out why it didn't work.

If you want to write something more rigorous that treats stdout and stderr separately, you'll need to use `proc_open()` instead: [PHP StdErr after Exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320608/php-stderr-after-exec)

Answer (score 0):

There are (perhaps insurmountable) difficulties when trying to execute sudo commands from a PHP script and from an external script called by PHP on SELinux enabled machines.

Make sure you use Linux directory path in your command

Linux won't let apache change the group id of the process by default.

You may need to use another solution, like make the PHP script deposit a file in  a directory which is monitored by cron or inotify and which will call another script with root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it does not work on Linux. Command `pushd` is defined in windows shell only.  The path on linux must use forward and not back slashe as separator.

Comment: No, bash also has pushd and popd. The problem here is the backslashes.