# exec() error responses

Tags: php, exec

Lets take this command for example:

```
$command = "echo '/just/for/the/test /heh/' | awk '//just// {print $1}'";
```

When directly copying it inside shell, I get the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: //just// {print $1}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ unterminated regexp
```

But, when I `exec()` it, I get status code 1 with no output:

```
exec($command, $output, $status);

var_dump( $command, $output, $status );

// string(69) "echo '/just/for/the/test /heh/' | awk '//just// {print $1}'"
// array(0) { }
// int(1)
```

How to retrieve the STDERR part of exec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should redirect stderr to stdout somehow like this

```
$stout = exec($command . " 2>&1", $output, $status);
```

See also here
[PHP StdErr after Exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320608/php-stderr-after-exec)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that one has hell of an answer on the subject. Bad thing it didn't show up on related questions when I asked. *Also, your answer is a tad faster than @Vlad's + you have less rep., so - accepted.*

Comment: Well, thank you :) I actually thought his answer was faster & also more extensive. But I won't complain for sure.

Answer (score 3):

with `exec()` the only way i can think of is to redirect STDERR to STDOUT in the command you are executing, like:

```
$command = "echo '/just/for/the/test /heh/' | awk '//just// {print $1}' 2>&1";
```

an alternative to `exec()` is to use the `proc_open()` family of function. With `proc_open()` you execute the command and open file pointers to STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR from which you can read / write

see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) for more info