# Creating a cron job for mysqldump

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to create a cron job for database backup.

This is what I have so far:

mysqldump.sh

```
 mysqldump -u root -ptest --all-databases | gzip > "/db-backup/backup/backup-$(date)" 2> dump.log

 echo "Finished mysqldump $(date)" >> dump.log
```

Cron job:

```
 32 18 * * * /db-backup/mysqldump.sh
```

The problem I am having is the job is not executing through cron or when I am not in the directory.

Can someone please advise.  Are my paths incorrect?

Also, the following line I'm not sure will output errors to the dump.log:

```
 mysqldump -u root -ptest --all-databases | gzip > "/db-backup/backup/backup-$(date)" 2> dump.log
```

What worked:

```
 mysqldump -u root -ptest --all-databases | gzip > "../db-backup/backup/backup-$(date).sql.gz" 2> ../db-backup/dump.log

 echo "Finished mysqldump $(date)" >> ../db-backup/dump.log
```

Comment: Your example should work. How do you make sure that is *not executing*?

Comment: Well, if I'm in the directory and type ./mysqldump.sh it works; however, if I cd .. and type say ./db-backup/mysqldump.sh then the log and back is not taken.  Also, the above cron job was set to 18:32 to test.  18:32 passed an not backup was taken.

Comment: You should use an absolute path the log file. Like `/var/log/mysql.dump.log`. Make sure that the file is writable by the cron user. Note: Jobs listed in /etc/crontab or /etc/cron.d* will be executed as root. Also there is a per user crontab mechanism. Such cronjobs will run with same privileges as the user to which the crontab belongs

Comment: Are you showing your entire mysqldump.sh? or just portions of it? Im with hek2mgl - likely either permissions or path. Test a simple script in the same directory that just sends an email or notifies you that it's run.

Comment: Hi, I am showing the entire file

Comment: Are you (as a user) allowed to write to root '/'?   That's where you're trying to create dump.log after a `cd ..`

Comment: Hi, I see dump files at the very top directory. It seems it may be outputting the log and backup to the very top level directory?

Comment: I'm logged into root and and file permissions on shell file -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root

Comment: I think the solution may be ../db-backup/mysqldump.sh

Comment: Thank you all for the help. It is working now. Update shows changes

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of things you can check, though more information is always more helpful (permissions and location of file, entire file contents, etc).

1. It can never hurt to preface the `mysqldump.sh` file with the [Shebang syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for your environment. I would venture to guess `#!/bin/bash` would be sufficient.
2. Instead of `mysqldump -u ....` use the absolute path `/usr/bin/mysqldump` (or where ever it is on your system). Absolute paths are always a good idea in any form of scripting since it's difficult to say if the user has the same environment as you do.

As for storing the errors in dump.log, I don't believe your syntax is correct. I'm fairly sure you're piping the errors from `gzip` into dump.log, not the errors from `mysqldump`. This seems like a [fairly common question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119520/run-mysqldump-via-php-exec-pipe-to-gzip-return-mysqldump-stderr) which arrives at the answer of `mysqldump $PARAMS | gzip -c dump-$(date)`