# How to launch properly php cli script in phpunit test?

Tags: php, phpunit, command-line-interface

I need to test some php cli script which uses stdout, stderr and return error code.

- [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) seems that it does not return stderr.
- [system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) does not return stdout (only last line), stderr.

Comment: I would advice [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open) then. It's a bit unwieldy though :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320608/php-stderr-after-exec ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proc_open could be used.

File: script.php

```
echo 'Standart output'; //stdout

error_log('Error output'); //stderr

exit(1); //return
```

File: test.php

```
<?php

$descriptorspec = array(
    1 => array("pipe", "w"), // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
    2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);

$process = proc_open('php script.php', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
if (is_resource($process))
    {
    echo 'stdout: ' . stream_get_contents($pipes[1]) . PHP_EOL;
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    echo 'stderr: ' . stream_get_contents($pipes[2]) . PHP_EOL;
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    $return_value = proc_close($process);
    echo 'return: ' . $return_value . PHP_EOL;
    }
```