# Getting Java Compile Error in PHP

Tags: java, php, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, javac

I'm trying to get the compile error for exec("some javaPath/javac", $output, $exit).
I tried print_r($output) and implode($exit) but I noticed the print_r gives an empty error if it fails to compile and implode only gives the error code.

Is there a way to get the compile error? For example, would it possible to get which line had a syntax error?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320608/php-stderr-after-exec

Answer (score 0):

How about displaying the value of `$exit`?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is probably sending the error info to the error stream rather than to standard output.  The two go to the same place in a terminal/console window, but a program reading output won't see errors and vice versa.

You might try `exec('some javaPath/javac 2>&1', $output, $exit);`, and see if that shows you any more info.  In Linux, it should.  In Windows, maybe someone else knows...

Comment: var_dump returns string(0) "" 
it doesn't add anymore information.