# PHP error_log after Exec()

Tags: php, apache, typo3, stderr, error-log

When calling the php function `exec` the output of the `stderr` is going the default `error_log` of apache. I have a server with many TYPO3 installations. And TYPO3 uses exec alot for image handling. My problem is that I get tons of

```
"/usr/local/bin/gm identify: Improper image header (typo3temp/pics/...."
```

or

```
"/usr/local/bin/gm convert: Unable to open file ..."
```

in the error_log. But there is no timestamp, no process ID, no process owner, no IP or anything else which could really help. Just the output.

Is there a way to add some useful information?

Comment: This might be helpfull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320608/php-stderr-after-exec

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't really helps. I know that I can redirect stderr in my own scripts. But I'm talking about scripts which aren't coded by me. 
So I'm searching for more general solution without modifying any php code.

Comment: So you want to manipulate how apache logs errors right? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

Comment: In general ... yes. But apache/php don't use the configured log format when php exec function outputs something to stderr ;-(