# Can't import module in python

Tags: php, python, module, package, python-import

I'm trying to use [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sc2reader/0.6.5) python library in my website. Now, I've downloaded the `sc2reader-0.6.5-py3.3.egg` file and transferred the `sc2reader` folder in some random directory on my FTP account. I've also created files called `test.py` and `test.php` in the same directory. `Test.php` executes the `test.py`, and `test.py` imports the `sc2reader` library.

This is the code in the `test.py`:

```
import sys
import sc2reader
print 'Works'
```

And it doesn't run, if I remove the second line (`import sc2reader`), it runs just fine.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
/random_dir
L________/sc2reader
         L_____ __init__.py
         L______/other_stuff
L________test.py
L________test.php
```

Any help is much appreciated. :P

Comment: Is there an error message (e.g. in your web server logs)? Can you run you python script from the command line? What are the permissions on sc2reader? You might want to see what goes out to stderr - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320608/php-stderr-after-exec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs of sc2reader](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sc2reader/0.6.5#installation):

> Install from the latest release on PyPI with pip:
>
> `pip install sc2reader`
>
> or easy_install:
>
> `easy_install sc2reader`

The `egg` file you downloaded is meant to be installed using easy_install. You can do this by running:

`easy_install sc2reader-0.6.5-py3.3.egg`.

I would recommend just installing with `pip` under [`virtualenv`](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). That way, when Python or a library you use is updated, your environment doesn't change with them and your application will continue to work.

Comment: I managed to get it working by doing a clean install of the module and setting the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like sc2reader is not in your PYTHONPATH. Open Python, without the quotes, type 'import sys' then 'sys.path'. Put sc2reader in one of the paths listed and see if it runs.