# How to get coverage for a PHP CLI application?

Tags: php, shell, phpunit, code-coverage

I want to add acceptance tests to a command line application written in PHP. The PHPUnit tests are using `proc_open` to run the application, as suggested in
[PHP StdErr after Exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320608/php-stderr-after-exec), which works fine.

Nevertheless, the code coverage is not collected. A report is produced, showing 100% coverage for interfaces and empty classes, and 0% for everything else.

How can I get the code coverage for the CLI application with PHPUnit?

Comment: Can you give us a minimal example of the code you are trying to cover?

Comment: In the end, we're talking about Symfony commands, that use application classes. If you want to have a closer look, you'll find them here: https://github.com/joomla-projects/joomla-pythagoras/tree/master/libraries/incubator/Cli/Command