# PHP: execute command as synchronous process and read stderr

Tags: php, process, synchronous, stderr

I have a PHP class that must launch a Java main as a separate process.
The execution must be synchronous and after its end I must read the stderr to handle and log potential errors.

I see that the most popular techniques to run separate processes from PHP are exec() and proc_open().
However, I do not understand which I should use and how.

Exec(), being synchronous and very easy to use, should be the best choice for me. However, from what I see [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320608/php-stderr-after-exec): [PHP StdErr after Exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320608/php-stderr-after-exec), it seems that the only way to get the stderr is to explicitly create a file for it. It does not seem to me like an elegant solution.

On turn, [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/it/function.proc-open.php) seems a really powerful tool, and it does allow direct, separate access to stdin, stdout and stderr.
For what I need to do, the code should be something like this:

```
$proc = proc_open($cmd,[2 => ['pipe','w']],$pipes);
$stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
proc_close($proc);
$error = var_dump($stderr)
```

The problem is proc_open is asynchronous, so if I get it right, I can not be sure that when I run stream_get_contents I will get any relevant message (errors might occur later!).

What should I do?

Comment: `stream_get_contents()` will wait for EOF on the pipe, which will happen when the program ends. So that makes it synchronous.

Comment: That's essentially what happens inside `exec()`, except it's doing it with stdout rather than stderr.

Comment: You can't have an assignment after `return`, since `return` exits from the function.

Comment: Did you look at the second answer in the question you linked to? It shows how to get `stderr` using `exec()` with output redirection in the command line.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for your great advices.
I thought that `stream_get_contents()` would just take a snapshot of the `stderr` stream (I also read the documentation but it does not mention EOF; I guess PHP docs are quite... concise).   

This definitely solves my issue! if you write an answer with it, I can mark it as the solution for my problem.  

As for the answer in the exec question, I did read it, but creating a new file with `posix_mkfifo()` just for redirecting stderr whenever I call a process seems a bit meh, doesn't it? I would avoid that unless it is absolutely necessary :)

Comment: The documentation says it reads the *remainder of a stream*. The remainder is everything until the stream ends, which is EOF.

Comment: (As for the `return`, yeah, that's a copy-paste error ahah)

Comment: Why do I need to write an answer when your code will work as written?

Comment: You don't need to create a new file with `mkfifo`. Use the solution with `command 2>&1 >/dev/null`

Comment: You only need the FIFO if you want to be able to get both stdout and stderr separately.